# Cabal test producing errors for Haskell

Tags: haskell, cabal, hspec

My `Main.hs` file takes in commandline arguments:

```
module Main (toLowerStr, Result(..), grade, main) where

...

grade :: [String] -> String -> String -> (Bool, Result, [Highlight])
    grade dictWords correctAnswer studentAnswer =
            ...

...

main :: IO ()
main = do
        args <- getArgs
        dict <- readFile $ args !! 0
        ...
```

Which works fine, except when I try to test. My testing file is

```
module Testing where

import Main
import Test.Hspec

main :: IO ()
main = do
        dict <- readFile "dict.txt"
        let dictWords = map toLowerStr $ lines dict
        hspec $ do
        describe "Validate passing answers" $ do
                it "Match should be verified exactly" $ do
                        grade dictWords "house" "house"
                              `shouldBe` (True, Perfect, [])
```

Yet when I run `cabal test` it still gives  me

```
Preprocessing test suite 'tests' for grade-0.1.0.0...
[2 of 2] Compiling Testing          ( src/HSpecTests.hs, dist/build/tests/tests-tmp/Testing.o )
Linking dist/build/tests/tests ...
Running 1 test suites...
Test suite tests: RUNNING...
tests: Prelude.(!!): index too large

Test suite tests: FAIL
```

I'm pretty sure it's failing because of the calls to `args` in `Main.main`, because the executable itself works fine, and I don't see `!!` being used anywhere else.

How do I get tests to run?

**EDIT**: Used pattern matching in `Main.hs`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
        [filename, correctString, studentString] <- getArgs
        ...
```

and the error is now

```
[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( src/Main.hs, dist/build/tests/tests-tmp/Main.o )
Linking dist/build/tests/tests ...
Running 1 test suites...
Test suite tests: RUNNING...
tests: user error (Pattern match failure in do expression at src/Main.hs:141:9-48)
Test suite tests: FAIL
```

**EDIT 2**: My entire `grade.cabal` file

```
-- Initial grade.cabal generated by cabal init.  For further documentation,
--  see http://haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/

name:                grade
version:             0.1.0.0
-- synopsis:            
-- description:         
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              Amos Ng <amosng@cmu.edu>
maintainer:          Amos Ng <amosng@cmu.edu>
-- copyright:           
category:            Language
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.8

executable grade
  main-is:             Main.hs
  -- other-modules:       
  build-depends:       base, split ==0.2.*
  hs-source-dirs:      src

test-suite tests
  ghc-options:         -Wall
  type: exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is:             HSpecTests.hs
  other-modules:       Main
  build-depends:       base, split ==0.2.*, hspec ==1.11.*
  hs-source-dirs:      src
```

Comment: What is below the "..."? Can you add the .cabal file (maybe you use the wrong src/main)

Comment: 1: Using `!! 0` is the same as just calling `head`. 2: try using pattern matching (and emitting a sensible error message) instead of doing either of those.

Comment: BTW: you should consider using the neat discovery feature of HSpec:  https://hspec.github.io/hspec-discover.html

Comment: @CarstenKönig I don't have the file with me right now but there's only two .hs files in `src`: Main.hs and HSpecTest.spec, and both use different module names. I don't think it'll be confused?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid ok, I updated the main file to use pattern matching. It's the culprit for sure. Any ideas?

Comment: It's just the same as before - your test seems to call the original Main.hs where you do your patternmatching now - obvious you don't want this (now you even need 3 arguments btw - not only 1) - you can easily test this by `cabal test --test-option="dict.txt"` - but as I said now you need 3 options because of your pattern-matching so give more)

Comment: If you could show us your `.cabal` file I could tell you why it takes the *wrong* main-method/module for your test

Comment: @CarstenKönig I've put my entire .cabal file there, does anything jump out at you?

Comment: @CarstenKönig adding `--test-option="dict.txt house house"` doesn't solve it (even though `grade dict.txt house house` works just fine after I do `cabal install`)

Comment: @CarstenKönig also i've put the entire testing file there

Comment: GHC will always use as the entry point the function named `main` out of the module named `Main`. Since `HSpecTests.hs` is the `Testing` module, not the `Main` module, its `main` is completely ignored, instead favoring the `main` from the `Main` module. You should break your logic out of the `Main` module, leaving the `Main` module as a command-line stub. Then you’ll want to exclude that from the test build, and change `module Testing` to `module Main` in `HSpecTests.hs`.

Comment: @icktoofay Ahhhh finally fixed it! Thanks so much, can you put that as an answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GHC will always use as the entry point the function named main out of the module named `Main`. Since `HSpecTests.hs` is the `Testing` module, not the `Main` module, its `main` is completely ignored, instead favoring the `main` from the `Main` module. You should break your logic out of the `Main` module, leaving the `Main` module as a command-line stub. Then you’ll want to exclude that from the test build, and change module `Testing` to module `Main` in `HSpecTests.hs`.

Comment: @wrongusername there are other ways to do this - the file your `Main`-Module is in has not to be called `Main.hs` and you can use different folders (for example `/src` and `/test`) to setup a sensible project structure - have a look at this Wiki article: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Structure_of_a_Haskell_project (this is a link from the above document but maybe you don't see it: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_write_a_Haskell_program)

Comment: @CarstenKönig I see, thanks a lot for the information! It is quite useful

Comment: @wrongusername @CarstenKönig I tend to put the main module for a program in a separate directory `driver`, see branch [`testing-a-programm`](https://github.com/sol/hspec-example/tree/testing-a-programm) of `sol/hspec-example` on GitHub.